# How am i gonna check how many classes passed after the last "past-2" in this class?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check how many classes passed after the last `"past-2 past-tooltip"` class. There are some class names named like `"past-0 past-tooltip"`,`"past-1 past-tooltip"`, `"past-2 past-tooltip"` and "past-3 past-tooltip". I want to check how many other classes passed after the last "past-2 past-tooltip". Every roll adds a class name between them.

```
var bruh = document.getElementsByClassName("past-2 past-tooltip")[document.getElementsByClassName("past-2 past-tooltip").length-1];

var hehe = document.getElementsByClassName("past-tooltip");

for(var i=0; i< hehe.length; i++){
    if (hehe[i].classList.includes("past-2")) {
        console.log("It was "+ i.length + " rounds ago.");
    }
}
```

Tried to check hehe's classlist if it had past-2 stop and tell how many classes passed after the "past-2" but code is wrong.

Code of the classes i am working with(disagree the hashes):

```
<div id="past-queue-wrapper"><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>ce8a09b6911f7e8d6ae716d440451addf7f1de4315dad031d85c796de17bdf26<br><span>Salt</span><br>37184947be20686752c083f25619d085<br><span>Random</span><br>42</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>7e1557639ab6286d847f7d6a004716a025a945244214edc00b0ae5579b4323ed<br><span>Salt</span><br>78a4c687158ea4179cad468c0d6f92c0<br><span>Random</span><br>5</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>19932486b5641de035c1d831d330eda3c77509a5ab7445739adbdc8f04601833<br><span>Salt</span><br>e5f37d6ca9b49fe65ca36411c588d871<br><span>Random</span><br>47</div></div><div class="past-2 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-2"><span>Hash</span><br>bd2469d3bb19b09d61a3b805286bceb2456158c1ba9f93307e1d72ef6225bf69<br><span>Salt</span><br>9dc0cac3c70b4dc50439492373a05885<br><span>Random</span><br>53</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>c41b02304d418bded5383d9e64d13a748a60d881aa9f712a39dc4ed7490d0ae9<br><span>Salt</span><br>ad4e31b782cf9e774d409b96e340f6d4<br><span>Random</span><br>52</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>cdc5db744232fb90f19145b30f266323186bb6f2bf2e3bcf49a34703f8276348<br><span>Salt</span><br>9934d7419fb24c8c5870ee529307567a<br><span>Random</span><br>24</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>004771c4fc7e949eb6d5295d0005132fe9b01134b6fdfa4c2e6600796bac7d35<br><span>Salt</span><br>a8caa068ef2fb1ff289124a3b8d32be7<br><span>Random</span><br>25</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>a23acd6ac7a6c362c01bac6afbb1195e1fd997c320a27accce5124bfce066dd6<br><span>Salt</span><br>8cbbc502f24d7c2f300e7e2aded3aa50<br><span>Random</span><br>18</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>0f2495eaa3cceae9ed4a86e1be4ebd2fe517d8a8c29ee4d7b9e5c905acc48503<br><span>Salt</span><br>a12f3086de7ab47b567294059537bda7<br><span>Random</span><br>48</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>2ee73f68f82fda7f97efd22c80ebfd14876c426200d33bc853a4737e7925122d<br><span>Salt</span><br>535381d50313cb4a54e33801b19e6dc0<br><span>Random</span><br>6</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>2e3908fe435c72ff18fb307d9b430aa0ca833a3e2fac5a069cabfcb88d6b221a<br><span>Salt</span><br>ead6dfe8f60aada35c733442038f42bd<br><span>Random</span><br>13</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>3ab9542fa66eb321beac927067ef79d09107b248573672dc54945c2cc849c986<br><span>Salt</span><br>ba854a650c6ed77ac9c254056b76e011<br><span>Random</span><br>40</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>ab0a7743fab5ecd574015c744b8886e1c112b59902db4e9282bd5acb7c0fac8a<br><span>Salt</span><br>029ab98c4b2b7e21876a73b8d5283860<br><span>Random</span><br>38</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>58ee4839c4aad0075e4a65dbac886fd5247f2252e77d195ad3c9ea998033911e<br><span>Salt</span><br>9c4e383191231889004a30de1f527048<br><span>Random</span><br>39</div></div><div class="past-2 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-2"><span>Hash</span><br>54f397d858c11710075f9168721d4690f2f7bba658a4c2d771c351b8a6af9d6c<br><span>Salt</span><br>eb04b1175b8430d001ea07a3b0d39eb3<br><span>Random</span><br>43</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>45fc196b79a94b5e5059598778053e41b8056f42038a1a9054308e2291d40ebb<br><span>Salt</span><br>1afb0a388806b55bb9bdbebe79251681<br><span>Random</span><br>52</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>7bfbdbfb4fdbd93da58c624661e345a6b2f325e6f41009ae6e82adce5dc141b7<br><span>Salt</span><br>8e65b81d39d68ca7f2cef93e7980c8d2<br><span>Random</span><br>42</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>17b54ab30d714408b69fc9d99539e47e17068f06de2bc73d878cee2938e020c2<br><span>Salt</span><br>25a8aeb700a60f850e1eae1273b88b37<br><span>Random</span><br>47</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>e690245429887007e4e8837ed9115f1dcfa80e2d02fe955863bb4b1e8f606869<br><span>Salt</span><br>09a510b34b49daaeca1498cc11557bf7<br><span>Random</span><br>6</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>f0d8ebbb2099f7db71ce80ca465244f5a1cc1d0f67f519e4322772c754b19050<br><span>Salt</span><br>f3f347a5a466b05799d26223365a9a5e<br><span>Random</span><br>38</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>0282f0b9491265137102f5fbb1395bf295f543c02950ad11a7568486f79f7d06<br><span>Salt</span><br>5ec07ca9d0c3855d56ea9b818b240c75<br><span>Random</span><br>26</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>17f2db270e0e5d2f51ba5337c47a07fa578aa0da580acdf4aacba970ea802722<br><span>Salt</span><br>ba2aacc7f359d2db71753cf53f39303d<br><span>Random</span><br>50</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>b09907d2e57953990158d0fb6538c509fa4de678a2816c65df8093445050a0c0<br><span>Salt</span><br>f6de70b6108204c8c4af0c18209983e0<br><span>Random</span><br>7</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>c2d5fb5005388616226393aaa7e3a1abc8753dd11b9e0104e58c79653f461b7a<br><span>Salt</span><br>043cac9640ca96e5db8a80ed9bf7addc<br><span>Random</span><br>51</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>09f2d6504b3f2d4cb6ddc984f4aa70869ff34898e88dceacaf27b44812e49d42<br><span>Salt</span><br>99b25955edae70b0fa6954c34b323e18<br><span>Random</span><br>5</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>9a018d7e4b2753f695bab7a25559d025a7106f1c6232baf4daac738e1254590e<br><span>Salt</span><br>93f10cb9d47f99fddfca99bf951c2ed6<br><span>Random</span><br>13</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>f2368324fcccc30d24e35d4f648260fca4dd3a6f026c88cdc6b901513ee1f76a<br><span>Salt</span><br>c83ba0f8f571c8fb2d359b1b270bcef3<br><span>Random</span><br>52</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>c4859be4664322df7c62143a0fd8f93638519d7f06b7727c26cf930ef297fbb4<br><span>Salt</span><br>bc5b42eb6f104634a27c2f1386ae0260<br><span>Random</span><br>7</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>b50059946cd1703f44be58de57a688764ad431e41a0c4f470e4e7715c29fdfdb<br><span>Salt</span><br>2b45e51b81f21850aa469d241fe1d3ec<br><span>Random</span><br>13</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>c9502ee25330d38c8662b80013ce07fa989229578ddaabccc14cacbbee822b10<br><span>Salt</span><br>a3bfba7bc3212dc7ff190060f2b69268<br><span>Random</span><br>2</div></div><div class="past-2 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-2"><span>Hash</span><br>f5c5b6b69fd8223d3f1ff7945cb2b65a4c06b9ba7b226e2067b2f37e1e3c9ec5<br><span>Salt</span><br>5cd5e82565ed70688cede79e4adcfa9b<br><span>Random</span><br>11</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>70369f9e57b4ea3930d3e1e9e055574fcbb2ba9cb601e4b5df231f65589e4b9a<br><span>Salt</span><br>c748a469a7d40b316bf9d1ba45e54870<br><span>Random</span><br>27</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>54170054a82f95bcea1eb7200599d4f5d8e4c441f81517ff08a7be94d63707bd<br><span>Salt</span><br>e4d8486e244c551fa989c05871488922<br><span>Random</span><br>5</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>416773ee57030d56c8e6a1ae3b37f730986598d92ec245d68e9182ea16bd9400<br><span>Salt</span><br>b2d9555cad38cdb1789221ccffdbc3d6<br><span>Random</span><br>15</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>d6d1d6502604994841c87b139a3ddc8df179b3a58401ef82cbda93f9c6037d0d<br><span>Salt</span><br>4d643f0ea8b5937edb0185a3b58f7ad2<br><span>Random</span><br>25</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>c8041ba8984cff1b83fea6a28e827cccb15eb1f85320cd85d0a8a0659f7c8672<br><span>Salt</span><br>6bdfc722ea252a76a674039ec568b0da<br><span>Random</span><br>27</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>1c33f656368a30ccb41a3245e752f363855af3c5fdf2c8885fe862b6b33df2f0<br><span>Salt</span><br>78e57e5aa8b0aa2476183ad96bcc0fbc<br><span>Random</span><br>20</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>df42d0a2f17cf69ac79ab02f3570b007c1e47734e2e3e97792d18728ed685160<br><span>Salt</span><br>d9011f8dce567e203d80be15da318e89<br><span>Random</span><br>29</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>3c00014a3a3a22675c74f7554731fbce1012e96af2625aa4e6e397ec7b4e8a0c<br><span>Salt</span><br>95d8d3e010673ce70876db20caf66b0c<br><span>Random</span><br>13</div></div><div class="past-2 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-2"><span>Hash</span><br>326ccc1d03db6604c3947f341a3a0dfc389b371020c74850facb1802b809cc5a<br><span>Salt</span><br>9295fa1f4313b9a209ffe2826cc30a3a<br><span>Random</span><br>11</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>e2d17a2abe8bf0dd5d2c80d26454aed5db3bba22525b637667d7945274941dfe<br><span>Salt</span><br>ff43da6ca01775ba03a1cc35d4be6c32<br><span>Random</span><br>38</div></div><div class="past-2 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-2"><span>Hash</span><br>12731e4cef12593a873825feb5f68f4cd5329c743e362b3724dfe08d2cbc1ed7<br><span>Salt</span><br>0ff00a8f4624acdf2bd08aaa8b2a7bdd<br><span>Random</span><br>45</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>b826d6f1e388b8b40b7b05254abee7162cd98abcad48ce0eb60b3a0de059dc33<br><span>Salt</span><br>b2c3a35f5f8df0abe3e0a3ae00c5f814<br><span>Random</span><br>12</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>4b451f87a4b1f7e25fbc297a89993d5c314699f4af5b199d075d561d9404d5ab<br><span>Salt</span><br>5cdc9256ff9a492fd56a84fc4fd53418<br><span>Random</span><br>7</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>361055b708d2b8dbd89348bd45a129b6caa4b15d2db5e2408567f3030ba64957<br><span>Salt</span><br>58a4f5b4a628d3879636fa85dd521694<br><span>Random</span><br>40</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>a080275ca8e753ffc6e55b6c37c38722848ca44a2c59f9a38e62fddba17dd625<br><span>Salt</span><br>4081dc165e4092ff08c03aa51bc66d7d<br><span>Random</span><br>46</div></div><div class="past-2 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-2"><span>Hash</span><br>90d412e4f3ed460a71578c8c8b7549cba28e50f05d7e39a387f0a65a5d548081<br><span>Salt</span><br>26c94b053a0d50634500fcb8d3b19f8c<br><span>Random</span><br>33</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>6d8ce6c8837d1eb3450cdd452c4a1e5baa450c473e7fb1abe2413183299839b3<br><span>Salt</span><br>ca3bc4a60124443aafc2ec5920e96bec<br><span>Random</span><br>26</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>c01882527b4b147c1eb6ce27833ca8c911cb627163ed5dce4218ec7f527dafe3<br><span>Salt</span><br>239b3b820ecc3d3cd48cd6a1dfa53f34<br><span>Random</span><br>42</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>62f124588e82436046914209397fa40572b968385673aaae66460bbbf608d532<br><span>Salt</span><br>b2259a44d1cefe498daae9732ed7023c<br><span>Random</span><br>24</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>b92f55349d2bc595838471a33af825a116291edcbc3f7060e09a75568b8b3157<br><span>Salt</span><br>56e7f809b245d0188d10149b177df3d0<br><span>Random</span><br>47</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>759f0ae8d67d2d1a97bebb24d0807e13cb850cd4e94bc87b12a24f05dc4a9a5b<br><span>Salt</span><br>511e4f22bcd38961ae40a02b8f4c5503<br><span>Random</span><br>52</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>f10d43ceb56c39782f6eb5353c0f18fd9c7d68127ce765d2b00ca735dc221cd2<br><span>Salt</span><br>9bc9c1a6be78ba7d149e63305dee2f50<br><span>Random</span><br>36</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>2ba79081d3d31e42bfdb70efc3a056afeb56b914faf6eec98e0583c4a656c0be<br><span>Salt</span><br>b554980e191735a2632a2fe39c7fc80d<br><span>Random</span><br>47</div></div><div class="past-2 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-2"><span>Hash</span><br>399703d2f1dc2e67c5b8bf6502e12f0ad38ec7b14a62a94255dd6b00e4de8792<br><span>Salt</span><br>54a6449ac0f998d924e90cc5b4eb1305<br><span>Random</span><br>21</div></div><div class="past-2 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-2"><span>Hash</span><br>0971e2f660a015a0be2c815275bfb93f7497968e8f6c79f4f01320a447e774b7<br><span>Salt</span><br>353dfa472277e10686e0cef6fbbc008c<br><span>Random</span><br>21</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>67e01ed23ea2a24e81cc90af30c851dc17f318b4787e0905b7b37055f424a713<br><span>Salt</span><br>b535683afae5d62fba04565399f8d59a<br><span>Random</span><br>41</div></div><div class="past-2 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-2"><span>Hash</span><br>bc515c7facb6d1a45b8e4746dd61951efb4a134f97f6f2e6b12de13ef1bad091<br><span>Salt</span><br>e39582f7568610dee111aedf6f67fc3e<br><span>Random</span><br>43</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>b373c694b61b61e963011221228fe19e0d5b0a19652693300b1371e3635c7b0f<br><span>Salt</span><br>d33d5aa317ddc300754275f97e258ad8<br><span>Random</span><br>31</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>8450410cc8453a96f4a47e5a26765cf3e16ad220b3801addbc58069fc97d0158<br><span>Salt</span><br>9afa6959d12953438145c5bd5fec056d<br><span>Random</span><br>5</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>101a2b8e52cecb6bd03355112675257f594d602ecd683460f60540418b7d744a<br><span>Salt</span><br>c7f3d7350e0f6c06baa039499f2b576a<br><span>Random</span><br>10</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>dcd6f98718223afaa5b1821aaf26f861ac20ee4adb0133ea7876dda7dedbb5ee<br><span>Salt</span><br>cba59e13e3e4a5efe2888ae586313c05<br><span>Random</span><br>44</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>295c09e2d93d9f568b1a9171e1e44f7f4b4c7f31720fb81d52ca9111aa80b652<br><span>Salt</span><br>d33610fb1f14e240c6a154a3907b3a95<br><span>Random</span><br>4</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>bfb3ab1319b5ef49fccf969890587f42148a2fc9f6004233cddb1f763c03a442<br><span>Salt</span><br>95cd8445278809e1f4ad22aefdc8f84d<br><span>Random</span><br>18</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>31707cec7016fb70dd7c88d801167dca78b785faf90d9a41f4bcbaa25364df35<br><span>Salt</span><br>981424798f08fc2f9b4b42d98a66818a<br><span>Random</span><br>46</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>bb692e1c93c6d782d8be5fa7402d814c6437e26b6a4014fdcc9cedb59628b69e<br><span>Salt</span><br>ed4942871807787f91a63e1029bf06b9<br><span>Random</span><br>16</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>13de79362ee9c328df35a2eb3df8d994e909a60b1b685d900c74f2bab819a18b<br><span>Salt</span><br>79079214a59fdce043350d5041bec224<br><span>Random</span><br>32</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>b03423e39750f1efee5d3d381735e3ba4d1545a15536add955c2c037e5d9089a<br><span>Salt</span><br>20a5e129e1140c635416acc5b5966ee7<br><span>Random</span><br>15</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>480bbd70410bca10cad0735cdc5a4cbc7841015be73e718b7239d5002b73711c<br><span>Salt</span><br>753d42ee0861c4c32313b6be091b3f76<br><span>Random</span><br>20</div></div><div class="past-2 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-2"><span>Hash</span><br>a9806c9e35343d7cbde03e85a01337e2bf6f59122effa5dbcaa8ec62abcc9225<br><span>Salt</span><br>40f9972e4734d0fb0d6ec0db6e4e472e<br><span>Random</span><br>33</div></div><div class="past-2 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-2"><span>Hash</span><br>157ac35eef670d243e38bf407a17fd09bea0808576f6ba4762ecc50cb482b0b0<br><span>Salt</span><br>a7e7a3e5e0d18e91867e53c9f78f9b3a<br><span>Random</span><br>21</div></div><div class="past-2 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-2"><span>Hash</span><br>a0faadbe5af5bb2726d493239f69917b7c0b229e19dd2483a5b179dc2a5748f7<br><span>Salt</span><br>099910392ce61b4896163a3b0056fa89<br><span>Random</span><br>9</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>76fc519801d66703bf194c21882bbfaab3a6dccff0564110aac1d811a8722a23<br><span>Salt</span><br>46e7cd5935a3fe7d7b621f3c297993c8<br><span>Random</span><br>31</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>ed27476834440636e612d1838efa24e9437a8ae5837f1e0504831efff24daf56<br><span>Salt</span><br>90d1a2b17bf0b3074e4f7421821ecafd<br><span>Random</span><br>14</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>80a64258738f557668636e02a4912f5a46ca6f0a50cfeeb92b057315de0285fd<br><span>Salt</span><br>1581fd27e486356a256e554e157822a5<br><span>Random</span><br>52</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>a2a09f052ada519921810cd1c3bdb6e0ead0934f7953cd3d6a1103604a86bbe1<br><span>Salt</span><br>05335226862e9562229ebf859dd425f2<br><span>Random</span><br>5</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>0bfcbcb7e986ff43627f2ac29e6f6046d0d674c94045a83147176aa30d63c892<br><span>Salt</span><br>4275c25ea2f2a703da9deb2d520ad474<br><span>Random</span><br>52</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>91e301deca25bf83a886ef6405895b8b25ca6ce9f17d9fddce8efd5f22ba9f6e<br><span>Salt</span><br>ffd3b6f5250799db90eaf1c21fc01833<br><span>Random</span><br>40</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>d45712593520221071769f6d3b068c4f917340afa8bdcea1d151c50a050b9777<br><span>Salt</span><br>5f239d9ca5663e96447c500940991b5b<br><span>Random</span><br>4</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>96682309fc356438063d720626d10d7dbc55828be3109adba7aaef4531c77b63<br><span>Salt</span><br>e4fb6c801934c298530f93b8a4ea0c6c<br><span>Random</span><br>44</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>1d8f62ad636d2cf0cc3593a43eed5ad9c911a7c184bcc88be2737e8495a75794<br><span>Salt</span><br>725e421428c998af2b411e49b98b1410<br><span>Random</span><br>30</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>141c9eb79f26ed9f5cc1d382222f99669e3bf50253419f5326f1edd692e90138<br><span>Salt</span><br>506302ab43ebb78d621c03540a219aec<br><span>Random</span><br>10</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>bde40cf8305e903867e04ed92d8d3cd538d05bd140383a44b76b61d5d9128fb8<br><span>Salt</span><br>0b160b4adece27b56596af1cbc56055e<br><span>Random</span><br>5</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>694b22c6dc8ccebcc8aaa27285f648b63adb1733479de82fccf5bb3b97e4e75a<br><span>Salt</span><br>6a2b0942548b28e8b7bd18427caf2774<br><span>Random</span><br>40</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>4ad2a4c929ca33d0ada0e89432bca5c33a27f1d87f11702b54024a618cbd7bc5<br><span>Salt</span><br>ff64bbda979d26158cbe3222faf5341b<br><span>Random</span><br>34</div></div><div class="past-2 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-2"><span>Hash</span><br>0b3a1e70d82876c8bde6ecae31e361280b5c7e2a6d7e00429f73fcd7fd5a1e12<br><span>Salt</span><br>98b5036b6bba7deb3b86fd262ba499a2<br><span>Random</span><br>43</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>6e7946dc63b97bc0b9f283dc1842eddfdec6b931fc1e39fd5caa70f8bd447a12<br><span>Salt</span><br>c8063625ef0b0a6aaa862355f94d6f3b<br><span>Random</span><br>18</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>e705b03fa7126a07474148306895d77d799f5f95d45f9efa475bc43690e7b792<br><span>Salt</span><br>3d9ed10d3cb7d4ea4583bb0550c3807c<br><span>Random</span><br>12</div></div><div class="past-2 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-2"><span>Hash</span><br>f8bc73f336f928e9d5d72569229ec419a3b52fae55774c032fcda354d7f8bf4b<br><span>Salt</span><br>d0a2516c5bc94dc661488f77cb5b965f<br><span>Random</span><br>1</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>be383ca3e82355cf268cfcc6430a91b1c4f3525701c41cf0e5ff2a96381e6fd7<br><span>Salt</span><br>9fa7bf11e58107a723594949b64b6961<br><span>Random</span><br>36</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>6e01f493999ae7e5ae2011f02c16ecf4ed2ae3e16c95939c1f1d183758d47920<br><span>Salt</span><br>700a40b32be4f83e049efda2059a70b9<br><span>Random</span><br>29</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>a3e665e9e1d3dd5047f634f171b1cadf2a5cc16273318a62902054190eeebe9a<br><span>Salt</span><br>9edd0ab142fe59d00935a780a0c0c1b7<br><span>Random</span><br>31</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>73af204075bdc93fdfc56f0808cd70acfb805b8a6c11ba106b1017532d60b2a8<br><span>Salt</span><br>083d91d0b6dfe8c897b9954f2610ca34<br><span>Random</span><br>5</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>ff7e9f77c48e93b8901997d902be2299caaee089cb0d092e984ca9b216f50977<br><span>Salt</span><br>2d63eba9a4d584a348400f8a783d4fce<br><span>Random</span><br>4</div></div><div class="past-2 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-2"><span>Hash</span><br>d8f57b612a5074ef9c905d0471278cc62e457ff0dc929244b124ed02117c3674<br><span>Salt</span><br>da4546fc9e2f3a8330f7d68fb3ba52fa<br><span>Random</span><br>45</div></div><div class="past-1 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-1"><span>Hash</span><br>4d8fe0b0fc2814066487ea0c946756e90eb1281a5253a8d280e64330bb36e222<br><span>Salt</span><br>9aee5d2394c03b9a48ee84d584201b09<br><span>Random</span><br>13</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>83c38e5526c7307491006657481ea6b987b8e6944185d25e1190f19d2746ef3a<br><span>Salt</span><br>332edc58402a01bf7d448d4722a6ee72<br><span>Random</span><br>28</div></div><div class="past-0 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-0"><span>Hash</span><br>4ffad098dd06698758ea130323a7b56c292a68c4095d6ab246a766a9345174f1<br><span>Salt</span><br>9a6d9b2ade0de1e7efb029b74fa832e6<br><span>Random</span><br>28</div></div><div class="past-2 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-2" style="left: -111px; top: 259px; display: none;"><span>Hash</span><br>4ff510672d9c97e33ab7690bf8686b6f5ba87e5659881cf656bbb7d1ea6d4ed4<br><span>Salt</span><br>c238077d3e9d821f0507499b65bd7dae<br><span>Random</span><br>35</div></div><div class="past-2 past-tooltip"><div class="past-color"></div><div class="past-queue-tooltip tooltip-2" style="left: -111px; top: 268px; display: none;"><span>Hash</span><br>47d39502e29eab40010c83c200393069093ae2f91e50bdf51c77aec24b658e57<br><span>Salt</span><br>e58d72d3d17af9645a5f9a53134ffb2e<br><span>Random</span><br>45</div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let last = getLastRound();

console.log( last );

function getLastRound() {
  let tip = document.querySelectorAll('.past-tooltip');

  let found = null;
  for (let i = tip.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (tip[i].classList.contains('past-2')) {
      if (found === null) {
        found = i;
      } else {
        return found - i;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
Ехpected output: 3
<div class="past-1 past-tooltip"></div>
<div class="past-0 past-tooltip"></div>
<div class="past-1 past-tooltip"></div>
<div class="past-2 past-tooltip"></div>
<div class="past-0 past-tooltip"></div>
<div class="past-1 past-tooltip"></div>
<div class="past-1 past-tooltip"></div>
<div class="past-2 past-tooltip"></div>
<div class="past-0 past-tooltip"></div>
<div class="past-1 past-tooltip"></div>
<div class="past-0 past-tooltip"></div>
<div class="past-1 past-tooltip"></div>
<div class="past-0 past-tooltip"></div>
<div class="past-1 past-tooltip"></div>
<div class="past-2 past-tooltip"></div> ←
<div class="past-1 past-tooltip"></div>
<div class="past-1 past-tooltip"></div>
<div class="past-2 past-tooltip"></div> ← 2
```

P.s.

```
var bruh = document.querySelectorAll(".past-2.past-tooltip");
var last = bruh[bruh.length - 1];

// instead of

var bruh = document.getElementsByClassName("past-2 past-tooltip")[document.getElementsByClassName("past-2 past-tooltip").length-1];
```

Comment: I only want the last console log. It console logs so much but i only want the last one.

Comment: It only says "3". And the last round always change every 15-20 second.

Comment: @zazachoops Because the querySelectorAll returns a static list of elements. You can wrap it with function, to update results with each function call (updated code).

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](https://i.gyazo.com/ac098696308c24546571d7d2f616cd97.png) it adds to the bottom every 20 seconds. and there are like nothing "past-2" but your code says that was 4 rounds ago.